# Returning JavaScript from asp.NET core controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I know there have been a lot of posts about this, but I cannot get any of the suggestions like...

```
Return Content("<script>alert('Hello world!');</script>")
```

... to work

We are just about to move from MVC to core - this worked in MVC and displayed a bootstrap modal, but I gather support for this method has been dropped in core.

This is what launches the modal 'PopupModal'

```
 Public Function ModalValidation(Message As String) As String
    Try
        Dim SB As New StringBuilder
        SB.Append("$(document).ready(function(){")
        SB.Append("$('#PopupModal').modal();")
        SB.Append("var vBody = document.getElementById('ModalBodyText');")
        SB.Append("vBody.innerHTML = '" & Message & "';")
        SB.Append("var vTitle = document.getElementById('ModalTitle');")
        SB.Append("vTitle.innerHTML = 'Validation';")
        SB.Append("vTitle.style.color = 'orange';")
        SB.Append("});")
        Return SB.ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex, 170, "Functions")
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

and on the controller

```
 Private Function Modal(ModalScript As String) As JavaScriptResult
        Return JavaScript(ModalScript)
    End Function
```

called like this

```
Return Modal(ModalValidation("Got here"))
```

It looks like I can recreate JavaScriptResult like this

```
Public Class JSResult
        Inherits ContentResult
        Public Sub New(ByVal script As String)
            Me.Content = script
            Me.ContentType = "application/javascript"
        End Sub
    End Class
```

But then what do I use in place of

```
Return JavaScript(ModalScript)
```

Thank you

Comment: isnt a best practice friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out

```
 Private Function Modal(ModalScript As String) As JSResult
        Return New JSResult(ModalScript)
    End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public ActionResult Welcome(){
  return Content("You are welcomed");
}
```

call this function through ajax and handle response.

Comment: For some reason Return Content doesn't do anything (see first part of the question)